# Shopping cart quantity not updating

Tags: python-3.6

I have a basic shopping cart.  I thought it was working but I have since discovered that even though it runs error free it is not doing one thing I thought it should and I am having trouble resolving the issue.

If I instantiate an item a second time, like this:

```
    item1 = Item(1, "Cucumbers", 1., 1, 'kg')
    item2 = Item(2, "Tissues", 2., 2, 'dozen')
    item3 = Item(3, "Tomatoes", 3., 5, 'pound')
    # item4 = Item(4, "Toothpaste", 1., 5, 'box')
    item4 = Item(4, "Cucumbers", 1., 2, 'kg')
```

What I want is for the quantity of cucumbers in item 1 to increase to '3'
and for item 4 to be auto-deleted.

I thought this was doing what I intended, but it's not:

```
            elif k == 'name':
                total_qty = v.qty + item.qty
                if total_qty:
                    v.qty = total_qty
                    continue
                self.remove_item(k)
            else:
                v[k] = item[k]
```

The code runs error free but I end up with two separate instances of cucumber.

Full code:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, unq_id, name, price, qty, measure):
        self.unq_id = unq_id
        self.product_name = name
        self.price = price
        self.qty = qty
        self.measure = measure


class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = dict()

    def __format__(self, format_type):
        if format_type == 'short':
            return ', '.join(item.product_name for item in self.content.values())

        elif format_type == 'long':
            return '\n'.join(f'\t\t{item.qty:2} {item.measure:7} {item.product_name:12} @ '
                             f'${item.price:1.2f} ... ${item.qty * item.price:1.2f}'
                             for item in self.content.values())

    def add(self, item):
        if item.unq_id not in self.content:
            self.content.update({item.unq_id: item})
            return
        for k, v in self.content.get(item.unq_id).items():
            if k == 'unq_id':
                continue
            elif k == 'name':
                total_qty = v.qty + item.qty
                if total_qty:
                    v.qty = total_qty
                    continue
                self.remove_item(k)
            else:
                v[k] = item[k]

    def get_total(self):
        return sum([v.price * v.qty for _, v in self.content.items()])

    def get_num_items(self):
        return sum([v.qty for _, v in self.content.items()])

    def remove_item(self, key):
        self.content.pop(key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    item1 = Item(1, "Cucumbers", 1., 1, 'kg')
    item2 = Item(2, "Tissues", 2., 2, 'dozen')
    item3 = Item(3, "Tomatoes", 3., 5, 'pound')
    # item4 = Item(4, "Toothpaste", 1., 5, 'box')
    item4 = Item(4, "Cucumbers", 1., 2, 'kg')
    cart = Cart()
    cart.add(item1)
    cart.add(item2)
    cart.add(item3)
    cart.add(item4)
    print("Your cart contains: {0:short}".format(cart))
    # cart.remove_item(1)
    print()
    print("Your cart contains: \n {0:long}".format(cart))
    print()
    print("The total number of items in your cart is: ", cart.get_num_items())
    print()
    print("The total cost of the items in your cart is: ", cart.get_total())
    print()
    cart.remove_item(3)
    print("Your cart contains: {0:short}".format(cart))
    print()
    print("Your cart contains: \n {0:long}".format(cart))
    print()
    print("The total number of items in your cart is: ", cart.get_num_items())
    print()
    print("The total cost of the items in your cart is: ", cart.get_total())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is:

```
def add(self, item):
    if item.unq_id not in self.content:
        self.content.update({item.unq_id: item})
        return
    else:
        self.content[item.unq_id].qty = self.content[item.unq_id].qty + item.qty
```